# running acceleo using Maven

Tags: maven, acceleo

I am trying to execute my acceleo project using maven. I have included all the dependencies in the pom file. It compile succesfully  (with command package). Here is my pom file:

```
 <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.acceleo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <useBinaryResources>false</useBinaryResources>
                        <usePlatformResourcePath>true</usePlatformResourcePath>
                        <acceleoProject>
                            <root>${project.basedir}</root>
                            <entries>
                                <entry>
                                    <input>src/main/java</input>
                                    <output>target/classes</output>
                                </entry>
                            </entries>
                        </acceleoProject>
                        <packagesToRegister>
                            <packageToRegister>org.eclipse.uml2.uml.UMLPackage</packageToRegister>
                        </packagesToRegister>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>src.AcceleoProject.files.Generate</mainClass>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>/${project.basedir}/src/main/java/src/AcceleoProject/files/model.uml</argument>
                            <argument>/${project.basedir}/src/main/java/src/AcceleoProject/files</argument> 
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.acceleo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.1</version>
                </dependency> 
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.acceleo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>model</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.3.v20120214-0359</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.acceleo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>engine</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.3.v20120214-0359</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.acceleo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0.v20111027-0537</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ecore</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.0.v20120127-1122</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.0.v20120127-1122</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.101.v20120125-1505</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.uml2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>uml</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.100.v201108110105</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.uml2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.0.v201105021727</version>
                </dependency> 
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
                    <artifactId>osgi</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.2.v20120110-1415</version>
                </dependency> 
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>contenttype</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.100.v20110423-0524</version>
                </dependency>
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                </dependency>

                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmi</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.0.v20120127-1122</version>
                </dependency> 
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.ocl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ecore</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2.v20111015-2027</version>
                </dependency>   
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ocl</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0.v20120206-0606</version>
                </dependency>   
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>lpg.runtime</groupId>
                    <artifactId>java</artifactId>
                    <version>v201004271640</version>
                </dependency>           
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0-v20070522</version>
                </dependency>           

                    </dependencies>
    </project>
```

After i give the command: exec:java i get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project AcceleoProject: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project AcceleoProject: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:352)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getBundle(InternalPlatform.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundle(Platform.java:1185)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.common.internal.utils.workspace.BundleURLConverter.resolveBundle(BundleURLConverter.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.common.internal.utils.workspace.BundleURLConverter.resolveAsPlatformPlugin(BundleURLConverter.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.environment.AcceleoEvaluationEnvironment.loadDynamicModules(AcceleoEvaluationEnvironment.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.environment.AcceleoEvaluationEnvironment.mapDynamicOverrides(AcceleoEvaluationEnvironment.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.environment.AcceleoEvaluationEnvironment.<init>(AcceleoEvaluationEnvironment.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.internal.environment.AcceleoEnvironmentFactory.createEvaluationEnvironment(AcceleoEnvironmentFactory.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.ocl.internal.evaluation.QueryImpl.getEvaluationEnvironment(QueryImpl.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.QueryImpl.getEvaluationEnvironment(QueryImpl.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.generation.AcceleoEngine.doEvaluate(AcceleoEngine.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.generation.AcceleoEngine.evaluate(AcceleoEngine.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AcceleoService.doGenerateTemplate(AcceleoService.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AcceleoService.doGenerate(AcceleoService.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AbstractAcceleoGenerator.generate(AbstractAcceleoGenerator.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AbstractAcceleoGenerator.doGenerate(AbstractAcceleoGenerator.java:158)
    at src.AcceleoProject.files.Generate.doGenerate(Generate.java:197)
    at src.AcceleoProject.files.Generate.main(Generate.java:159)
    ... 6 more
```

Any idea, what can be wrong with it ?

Thank you in advance 
ME

Comment: Your package layout looks really weird. '/src/main/java/src/AcceleoProject/files/model.uml' should first of all be in 'src/main/resources' and the package name is 'src.AcceleoProject.files'. Doesn't look right. Same problem with your 'mainClass'.

Comment: Hi I tried to remove all the files in the folder that you suggested:'src/main/resources'  but still is the same error !